# How do I disable Smart Quotes in the Eclipse Oxygen Configuration Arguments text area on Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, run-configuration

The Eclipse Oxygen app on Mac OS X has the 'Smart Quotes' feature enabled by default for the text area inputs of the 'Arguments' tab of the 'Run Configurations' dialog. This is immensely annoying - I *never* want smart quotes in arguments I am specifying for running an application.
I can turn the feature off each time I open the Arguments tab by opening the control menu, selecting the 'Substitutions' submenu, and then toggling 'Smart Quotes' off. I would really like to specify in some preferences somewhere that 'Smart Quotes' should default to 'off' in this situation (It is defaulted to 'off' elsewhere in Eclipse - it is only on in this one text input case.)

Comment: Have you considered turning them off system wide in the Keyboard Srttings?

Comment: I found that just after I posted my question. I'd rather turn it off just for Eclipse, though.